# Check if the location alert is dismissed

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I check if the user has responded to Location alert

“App Would Like to Use Your Current Location”
or
“App would like to send you push notifications”

I don't care which choice the user select I only need to know if the alert is dismissed,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't directly get a message when the user dismisses this alert, but you can implement CLLocationDelegate's `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status` method. Between that and checking CLLocationManager's static `authorizationStatus` property you can usually figure out whether the user has allowed location services in your app yet.

Answer (score 0):

Apple forbids it, so you can't do it!

Comment: No it's not tru , like Drew C mentioned you can use CLLocationDelegate to know if the user had respond,,

Answer (score -2):

Edit: aha I noticed now that you had tagged the question erroneously with `uialertview`.

For location alerts you can do:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    if (error.code ==  kCLErrorDenied) {
        NSLog(@"Location manager denied access - kCLErrorDenied");

        UIAlertView *alert = 
              [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location issue" 
                                         message:@"Your location cannot be determined." 
                                        delegate:self 
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    } 
}
```

For push notifications you can do (although the user might have responded or not):

```
UIRemoteNotificationType status = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
if (status == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone) {

     NSLog(@"User is not subscribed to receive push notifications");
}
```

Comment: Your answer assumes the question refers to an AlertView under the application's control.  The question refers to an alert sent by the system.

Comment: @Bogatyr Yah the OP had used the `uialertview` tag so that confused me. Edited answer now.

Comment: Thanks for your concern about duplication and trivial questions, but this is not my question!

Comment: OK, I see you've updated your answer.   Don't be so fast to jump on question posters :).